# Why is there no uncapitalize in most JS helper libraries

Tags: javascript, extjs, ember.js, underscore.js

Looking through JS helper libraries for strings like

[underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme)
[stringjs](http://stringjs.com/)

or those from

[Ember](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html)

only

Sencha's [ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.String)

provides a **uncapitalize** function.

Is there a reason for that? 
Why not providing a uncap function is your library is providing a cap function (all of them do...)?

Transitivity is important here.

**Example:**

```
"awordWithCamelCase".capitalize() => "AwordWithCamelCase"
"AwordWithCamelCase".uncapitalize() => "awordWithCamelCase"
```

Comment: Because there is usually no need for one - what do you need it for?

Answer (score 2):

Literally making something lower case? Because we have:

```
String('hello').toLowerCase();
```

as a built-in Javascript function. If this is not what you were asking, you need to make your question much clearer.

#### Additional note:

Sencha's ExtJS also has a `shoelace.tie()` method, and a `babyfood.mouthfeed()` method, and as a result it is impractically gloated.

Comment: Good answer. No need to do `String()` though; `'hello'.toLowerCase()`does the job.

Comment: Thanks. I do know that, I was just trying to be very explicit with him as this question is so simple it needs that. Basics first, shorthand later.

Comment: @dc2 see my example for clarification

Comment: @Jeremy S. oh that makes more sense! Thanks for the clarification. For gaping wholes like that (where I need them), I have my own extensions file that contains extensions from every library I use, in one spot. This would be a one-liner extension, so I recommend you just do that!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because there isn't much demand (or use) for such a function.

As @dc2 mentions in his answer most times one can just use `toLowerCase()`. The `uncapitalize` function is rather simple (from ExtJS source):

```
return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.substr(1);
```

The jQuery developers would probably argue that it would add unnecessary bloat to the library as a whole.

And, while ExtJS *is* nifty for some things, it's arguably "bloated".

Answer (score 2):

```
    function uncapitalize(text) {
         if(!text || typeof text !== "string") {
            return ''; 
         }

         return text.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + text.substr(1);
    }

    uncapitalize('Aaa');
    --> 'aaa'

    uncapitalize('AaA');
    --> 'aaA'

    'Aaa'.toLowerCase();
    --> 'aaa'

    'AaA'.toLowerCase();
    --> 'aaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you can do it yourself (`^.` means "first char") :

```
'AzeRty'.replace(/^./, function (m) { return m.toLowerCase(); }); // "azeRty"
```

Comment: you could clearly not do ```capitalize()``` yourself, can't you? ;)